# How to use JUMP function with F12 or Ctrl-Shift-O in C-Files?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I need the basic symbol jumping feature while I navigate my source code.
I mean while I open a C source code folder into the VScode-0.9.1, then I want to jump to one function's definition using `F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+O`, there is no response for `F12`, or an error message like “unfortunately we have no symbol information for the file”.

How can I get the symbol jump function? I think this is a basic and critical feature as a source code editor. Could you please give me some information or support? Thanks a lot!

[image: No outline support in C files]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no deeper language support for C files in Visual Studio Code. This will probably change in the future when the extension API for the editor will be public.

For now you have only syntax highlighting for C files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the future, will VScode support C/C++ IntelliSense, Symbol jumping/navigating feature?

Comment: In case anybody creates an extension for C and C++ then yes. Since C is one of the most used languages in the world I think the chance of getting an extension for it are relatively high. But I can't promise anything here.